# Opencart Method doesnot exists still page loads

Tags: php, opencart

I am working on an opencart project whne I go the page /sale/order/packingslip , I can see the page is loding and generating html output, but whwn I go to sale/order.php controller file I dont see the packingslip method being defined. it extends controller calss. May I know what am I missing here ?  Where can I find this method ?

Comment: Sure it's not a `vQmod`? They are evil.

Comment: My Mistake, yes its a vqmod , I should have checked that first. Thanks Ian

Comment: @IanBrindley - Considering the alternative of manually editing files with each extension, and on each upgrade, I'd consider them the lesser of two evils ;)

Comment: @JayGilford Are you serious!?

Comment: @IanBrindley - yes I am. Why would you want to have changes you'll lose with each iteration of upgrade for OpenCart? There's a reason over 90% of all extensions on the extension store use vQmod - It's quick, it works, it can be disabled easily restoring back to the original files, it requires no file edits - I'm not even sure why you'd suggest it's "evil"